# Using paypal IPN sample code but it doesnt work

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to setup Paypal IPN for my Skype bot but I can't get it to work. I am using the Paypal sample code found here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php but I keep on getting `We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 500: Internal Server Error` from Paypal's IPN simulator.

I really need help with this. I'm not good with PHP.

Comment: Please show your code here as well.

Comment: Its exactly the same as on github. Nothing was changed. @Fred